# Gap width larger on display: block

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have a question regarding the Display: block;

I made a section with 3 different columns. When you see the website on your phone, the columns will display among each other. When you see the site on your desktop the columns will display next to each other.

The only problem is the gap between the columns...

Does anyone know how I can make the gap between the columns larger?

Website;

https://www.spiralex.nl/

[image]

My code (css);

```
.blabla{
max-width: 1170px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){ 
  .blabla{
    display: grid;
  }
}

#column2{
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  max-width: 381px;
  max-height: 463px;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: .03571em;
 }

#column1{
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  max-width: 381px;
  max-height: 463px;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: .03571em;
}
#column3{
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  max-width: 381px;
  max-height: 463px;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: .03571em;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `padding`:

```css
.blabla > div {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Margin sets spacing between elements, so setting a margin will cause the `div`s two break. But `padding` sets spacing between the contour of the element and its content.